# C# How can I use this as a method?

Tags: c#

Original: I am using if statements in many methods. My original code works. But, it would be nice to create a method for them so I can call it every time I want to use it.

```
private void method()
{
  if (page_name == "SpecificPageName")
  {
      if (!TableHasElements)
      {
         // A: do something
         return;
      }
      else if (role != instructor)
      {
         // B: message("Access Denied")
         return;
      }
  }
  **// C: Open Page**
}
```

I would like to create a method for the if statements:
However, when I make a method and call the method it should be able to run "C" when A and B conditions are not met.

```
private void methodIWouldLikeToCall()
{
    if (!TableHasElements)
    {
        // A: do something
        return;
    }
    else if (role != instructor)
    {
        // B: message("Access Denied")
        return;
    }
}
private void method()
{
    if (page_name == "SpecificPageName")
    {
        methodIWouldLikeToCall();
    }
    // C: Open Page**
}
```

Comment: Do you perhaps need an `else`?

Comment: `it doesn't work` can you explain?

Comment: For the record, `something` will always be equal to `something` so your code makes little sense. Perhaps you could at least use dummy variables so we can see what things are supposed to be the same and what are supposed to be different. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem and this is neither.

Comment: You could make `methodIWouldLikeToCall` return a `bool` (true if either A or B was executed, false if not) and use this return value to conditionally jump out of `method`.

Comment: @John Hello. Sorry I am new to this and thought it wasn't necessary to include variable names. However, I have edited the post. It should open the page if the Table has elements and the role is "instructor". Thank you for your help.

Comment: *"I [...] thought it wasn't necessary to include variable names"*. Strictly speaking it probably wasn't but the logic wasn't clear from what you originally had and that was, for me at least, obscuring the point of the question.

Comment: @John   Thank you for pointing out my lack of details. This is my first post and as a student, I am learning as much as I can. I will make sure to be more descriptive and include as many variable names as possible in future posts. Your solution has worked as it should. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your new method needs to return a result that will enable you to decide whether or not to continue with the original method, e.g.

```cs
private bool methodIWouldLikeToCall()
{
    if (!TableHasElements)
    {
        // A: do something
        return true;
    }
    else if (role != instructor)
    {
        // B: message("Access Denied")
        return true;
    }

     return false;
}

private void method()
{
    if (page_name == "SpecificPageName")
    {
        if (methodIWouldLikeToCall())
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    **// C: Open Page**
}
```

You may want to reverse the use of `true` and `false` if that is more natural in the circumstances. You might also remove the nesting in the original method and use a single `if` statement with `&&`, if that's appropriate.

Comment: This is totally correct, as per the OP's requirements, but I'd like to point out that this code is spaghetti and is difficult to follow and maintain.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I don't necessarily disagree but I don't think that we have a clear enough picture of what the actual original code looks like to make concrete recommendations as to how it should be improved. At least the intent is a bit clearer now that there are fewer `something`'s.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, I'm not criticizing your answer. I'm just trying to point out to the OP and future readers about the poor quality of the code to begin with.